# Why does compiling angular dependencies from es2015 to esm2015 remove html tags in environment?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, intellij-idea, angular-material2

As soon as the generating browser application bundle is over intellij can't resolve the html tags anymore. Why is that?

Also i found out if i don't add the AngularMaterialModule to the AppModule i keep all angular material html tags.

```
Compiling @angular/cdk/accordion : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/expansion : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/icon : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/cdk/text-field : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/input : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/list : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/menu : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/select : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/cdk/layout : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/tooltip : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/paginator : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/progress-spinner : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/sidenav : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/snack-bar : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/sort : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/cdk/table : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/table : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/tabs : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/toolbar : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/tree : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/badge : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/grid-list : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/radio : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/material/datepicker : es2015 as esm2015
```

[Unknown html tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb9aX.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must be [WEB-50675](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50675), it's fixed in upcoming 2021.1.2 update